# Не могу понять почему как сделать такой recv чтобы принимал столько байтов сколько байтов в сообoении клиента python sockets

Tags: python

Мой сервер имеет два recv. Первый принимает длину строки, которую отправляет клиент в виде числа завернутого в байтовую строку. Второй принимает уже само сообщение о размере котором мы сообщили в
первом recv его строку мы просто сделали integer и сообщение приходит и размер тоже приходит, но
мне сказали что их смущает первый recv.

**пожалуйста помогите мне придумать что делать с первым recv или подскажите другой способ принятия того количества байтов, который отправил мне мой клиент, чтобы сообщение было целым и могло быть любой длины !**

Вот код сервера:

```
import socket

Server = socket.socket()
Server.bind(('localhost', 2222))
Server.listen()

def handle_client():
    conn, addr = Server.accept()
    print(f'Got connection from: {addr}')
    num_of_bytes = conn.recv(250)
    len_of_bytes = int(num_of_bytes)
    print(num_of_bytes)
    data = conn.recv(len_of_bytes)
    print(data.decode('utf-8'))
    data2 = data.upper()
    conn.send(data2)


handle_client()
```

А вот код клиента:

```
import socket

client_sock = socket.socket()
client_sock.connect(('localhost', 2222))

message = input('>>> ')
def send(msg):
    data = msg.encode('utf-8')
    length = bytes(str(len(data)), 'utf-8')
    client_sock.send(length)

    client_sock.send(data)
    print(client_sock.recv(int(length)).decode('utf-8'))

send(message)
```

Comment: Меня он то же смущает. Как и в принципе способ передачи длины. Часто (но не всегда) tcp сокеты действительно передают такие порции данных, которые вы отправляете. В данном случае это вас спасает. Но при определенных событиях в сети все может сломаться. Например вам надо передать данные "123456". Вы берете их длину "6" и передаете. А tcp отправляет за 1 раз "6123456" и как вы теперь поймете что надо только первый байт использовать как длину, а остальное как данные ?

Comment: Вообще есть 2 подхода. **1** Двоичный протокол. Длину можно передать либо полем фиксированого размера в двоичном виде (т.е. если например у вас не может быть более 255 байт в данных то кодируете длину одним байтом от b'\x00' до b'\xFF'), либо используете какую либо систему кодирования поля переменной длины (например ASN.1 BER). **2** Используете символьный протокол, как пытаетесь сейчас, посылаете длину как сейчас в виде десятичного числа, но после строки ставите какой либо разделитель, например перевод каретки (`\n`)

Comment: При чтении в любом случае читаете в цикле в буфер данные блоками, скажем по 4096 байт. И анализируете после каждого чтения буфер на полноту, согласно тому протоколу передачи длины, который вы выбрали

Comment: P.S. второй conn.recv(len_of_bytes) меня то же смущает, он не обязан вам вернуть строго len_of_bytes байт, он обязуется вернуть не более len_of_bytes байт, т.е. от одного до len_of_bytes. И один блок данных длиной 3 байта вполне может вам придти за три раза, по 1 байту. так что цикл чтения до тех пор пока все требуемые байты не приняты, необходим